# There is no option on Import Packages in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my first time develop light video game and I choose Unity as my IDE. But after I install it, I found there is no other option in `Assets->Import Packages`menu, there is only `Costum Packages`.

Menus that should be like these following picture :

[image]

Can you guys tell me where or whats is the mistake? I need that solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can import .unitypackage just by double click that package (if you have it on your PC) or by download from the asset store.
You need to know that Unity will use package manager instead of unitypackage in the future (righ now unitypackage is legacy and works at the same time as Package manager), that's why they changed the menu.

Answer (score 0):

download here
You can get those assets from the asset store in free of cost:
    https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351

Answer (score -2):

everything under 'custom packages' is stuff that comes with unity. clicking on 'custom package' will let you import your own package

Comment: If you read the question again, the OP mentioned he is unable to see any other option than "Custom package..."

Answer (score -3):

**You can get those assets from the asset store in free of cost:**

> https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351

Comment: OP is asking how to get the other import options, not where to find them.